# Uninitialized member variables are are initialized when creating new object in loop

Tags: c++, file, initialization

I am writing a program where lines are read from a file. Each line contains data about a "student". All of the code I am going to post might seem a bit excessive, but it really is a very simple program with a very specific bug, so I just included all of it so anyone could easily try it out on their own.

I think problem is in the while-loop in the `StudentList` constructor.
A new `Student` object is created, and even though the member variables `id` and `gpa` of a `Student` object is not initialized in its constructor, they seem to be initialized with the values provided by the previous line in the file, that is, the values assigned to the object created in the previous loop of the while statement. But this should be impossible since the object is destroyed after each loop. More explanation and code below:

Header file to `Student`

```
// Student.h

#pragma once
#include<string>
#include<sstream>

/*
   Class representing a student.
*/
class Student
{
public:
    Student(std::string studentInformation);
    std::string getFirstName();
    std::string getLastName();
    std::string getName();
    int getId();
    double getGPA();

private:
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
    int id;
    double gpa;

};
```

Source file to `Student`:

```
// Student.cpp
#include "Student.h"
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

/*
    Purpose: Constructs a student.

    @param studentInformation Can contain first and last name, id and gpa score.
    All separated by whitespace.
*/
Student::Student(string studentInformation)
{
    // If no information about the student was provided:
    if (studentInformation.empty())
        cout << "THIS STUDENT IS EMPTY!" << endl;

    // Prints the object's id and gpa values. These should be uninitialized.
    cout << "current values gpa, id : " << id << ", " << gpa << endl;

    stringstream studentStream(studentInformation);
    cout << "chars in stream: " << studentStream.rdbuf()->in_avail() << endl;

    // Precaution just to check if there are any values to assign.
    if (!studentStream.rdbuf()->in_avail() == 0)
    {
        studentStream >> firstName;
        studentStream >> lastName;
        studentStream >> id;
        studentStream >> gpa;
    }
}


string Student::getFirstName()
{
    return firstName;
}

string Student::getLastName()
{
    return lastName;
}

string Student::getName()
{
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
}


int Student::getId()
{
    return id;
}

double Student::getGPA()
{
    return gpa;
}
```

Header file to `StudentList`

```
#pragma once

#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>
#include<algorithm>

#include "Student.h"

class StudentList
{
public:
    StudentList(std::string filePath);

    Student getValedictorian();  // Not used here
    std::vector<Student> getHonorRollStudents();  // Not used here
    std::vector<Student> getFailingStudents();  // Not used here

//private:
    std::vector<Student> students;

};
```

Source file to `StudentList`

```
#include "StudentList.h"
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

/*
    Purpose: Initializes a member vector that holds elements of type Student.
    The values to initialize each element with are obtained from a .txt file.

    @param filePath The path to the file from which we should read the data from.
*/
StudentList::StudentList(string filePath)
{
    ifstream studentFile(filePath);

    string lineContents;  // Holds the content of each line in the file.
    int counter = 1;  // Counts the number of lines read.

    while (!studentFile.eof())
    {
        cout << "\nfile line counter: " << counter++ << endl;
        getline(studentFile, lineContents);
        cout << "current line content in file: " << lineContents << endl;

        // Create a new student from the lines content.
        // This object should not have any initialized data about name, id or gpa.
        Student s(lineContents);

        // Check what values were added to the object.
        cout << "name: " << s.getName() << " id: " << s.getId() << " gpa: " << s.getGPA() << endl;

        // Put the object in the vector
        students.push_back(s);
    }
    studentFile.close();

    // Sort the vector based on the gpa value, in descending order
    sort(students.begin(), students.end(), [](Student &s1, Student &s2)
                                           {
                                               return s1.getGPA() > s2.getGPA();
                                           });
}
```

My text file that I read data from:

```
Shirley Temple 0235 93.8
John Appleseed 4325 89.2
Debbie Downer 9245 70.3
```

And finally the main function:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Student.h"
#include "StudentList.h"

using namespace std;

// Practical method to write relevant info about a Student:
void printStudent(Student student)
{
    cout << "\nName: " << student.getName() << endl;
    cout << "ID: " << student.getId() << endl;
    cout << "GPA: " << student.getGPA() << endl;
}

int main() {

    // Create a new StudentList object that adds students to its vector,
    // based on the data obtained from the file:
    StudentList list("C:/Users/UserName/Documents/students.txt");

    // Check how many students were created and added to the vector in list.
    cout << "\n students vector length: " << list.students.size() << endl;

    for (Student s : list.students)
        printStudent(s);

    //Student s2("");
    //printStudent(s2);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
file line counter: 1
current line content in file: Shirley Temple 0235 93.8
current values gpa, id : -858993460, -9.25596e+61  // Not already initialized, which is expected.
chars in stream: 24
name: Shirley Temple id: 235 gpa: 93.8

file line counter: 2
current line content in file: John Appleseed 4325 89.2
current values gpa, id : 235, 93.8  // Already explicitly Initialized! How come!?
chars in stream: 24
name: John Appleseed id: 4325 gpa: 89.2

file line counter: 3
current line content in file: Debbie Downer 9245 70.3
current values gpa, id : 4325, 89.2  // Already explicitly Initialized! How come!?
chars in stream: 23
name: Debbie Downer id: 9245 gpa: 70.3

file line counter: 4
current line content in file:
THIS STUDENT IS EMPTY!
current values gpa, id : 9245, 70.3  // Already explicitly Initialized! How come!?
chars in stream: 0
name:   id: 9245 gpa: 70.3

file line counter: 5
current line content in file:
THIS STUDENT IS EMPTY!
current values gpa, id : 9245, 70.3  // Already explicitly Initialized! How come!?
chars in stream: 0
name:   id: 9245 gpa: 70.3

 students vector length: 5

Name: Shirley Temple
ID: 235
GPA: 93.8

Name: John Appleseed
ID: 4325
GPA: 89.2

Name: Debbie Downer
ID: 9245
GPA: 70.3

Name:
ID: 9245
GPA: 70.3

Name:
ID: 9245
GPA: 70.3
Press any key to continue . . .
```

So I am absolutely very confused about how it can be possible that the `id` and `gpa` of every `Student` object created after the first read line in the `StudentList` constructor, is initialized with the values of the previously created object.
As a recap, the beginning of the `Student` constructor looks like this:

```
Student::Student(string studentInformation)
    {
        // If no information about the student was provided:
        if (studentInformation.empty())
            cout << "THIS STUDENT IS EMPTY!" << endl;

        // Prints the object's id and gpa values. These should be uninitialized.
        cout << "current values gpa, id : " << id << ", " << gpa << endl;
```

As far as I know, there is no way the `id` and `gpa` members can have been explicitly initialized before the `cout` statement. Yet, all objects created after the first one in the `StudentList` constructor are initialized when the `cout` above is executed. How can this be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the memory is uninitialized, everything can be in it!

It seems the compiler reuses the "old" memory addresses of old temporary variables.

Initialize *all* members like that in ctor:

```
Student::Student(string studentInformation)
 :firstname(), lastname(), id(0), gpa(0)
{ 
... ctor stuff
}
```

Comment: Oh, ok I see. And this does not happen to <code>firstName</code> and <code>lastName</code> because they are default initialized to the empty string?

Comment: Yes, but it's good style to initialize all members in constructor's initializer list.